# double-initialization of spring beans in jetty 7.1.4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

When I start a webapp that has a spring configuration in jetty, I see two calls to initialization (@PostConstruct methods). web.xml declares a ContextLoaderListener and provides contextConfigLocation.

This seems wrong. (spring 3.0.3). Is there something I've done?

**EDIT**

My web.xml calls out both the DispatcherServlet and the org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener. If I remove the later, I stop seeing two initializations --- but my app fails in the jetty-maven-plugin with

```
No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
```

**EDIT 2**:

Got it. The dispatch servlet will find some context files by conventional name (*-servlet.xml), and so calling that file out again in the contextConfigLocation led to it being loaded twice.

Stack trace 1:

```
Segmenter.initialize() line: 63 
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39  
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597  
InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(Object) line: 340    
InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(Object, String) line: 293    
CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor).postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object, String) line: 130 
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(Object, String) line: 394    
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).initializeBean(String, Object, RootBeanDefinition) line: 1405    
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).doCreateBean(String, RootBeanDefinition, Object[]) line: 519 
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).createBean(String, RootBeanDefinition, Object[]) line: 456   
AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject() line: 291 
DefaultListableBeanFactory(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry).getSingleton(String, ObjectFactory) line: 222  
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactory).doGetBean(String, Class<T>, Object[], boolean) line: 288    
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactory).getBean(String) line: 190   
DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons() line: 574 
XmlWebApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).finishBeanFactoryInitialization(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) line: 895 
XmlWebApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).refresh() line: 425    
ContextLoaderListener(ContextLoader).createWebApplicationContext(ServletContext, ApplicationContext) line: 276  
ContextLoaderListener(ContextLoader).initWebApplicationContext(ServletContext) line: 197    
ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent) line: 47  
JettyWebAppContext(ContextHandler).startContext() line: 645 
JettyWebAppContext(ServletContextHandler).startContext() line: 200  
JettyWebAppContext(WebAppContext).startContext() line: 995  
JettyWebAppContext(ContextHandler).doStart() line: 588  
JettyWebAppContext(WebAppContext).doStart() line: 381   
JettyWebAppContext.doStart() line: 114  
JettyWebAppContext(AbstractLifeCycle).start() line: 55  
ContextHandlerCollection(HandlerCollection).doStart() line: 165 
ContextHandlerCollection.doStart() line: 162    
ContextHandlerCollection(AbstractLifeCycle).start() line: 55    
HandlerCollection.doStart() line: 165   
HandlerCollection(AbstractLifeCycle).start() line: 55   
JettyServer(HandlerWrapper).doStart() line: 92  
JettyServer(Server).doStart() line: 228 
JettyServer.doStart() line: 67
```

Stack trace 2:

```
Segmenter.initialize() line: 63 
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39  
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597  
InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(Object) line: 340    
InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(Object, String) line: 293    
CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor).postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object, String) line: 130 
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(Object, String) line: 394    
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).initializeBean(String, Object, RootBeanDefinition) line: 1405    
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).doCreateBean(String, RootBeanDefinition, Object[]) line: 519 
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).createBean(String, RootBeanDefinition, Object[]) line: 456   
AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject() line: 291 
DefaultListableBeanFactory(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry).getSingleton(String, ObjectFactory) line: 222  
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactory).doGetBean(String, Class<T>, Object[], boolean) line: 288    
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactory).getBean(String) line: 190   
DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons() line: 574 
XmlWebApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).finishBeanFactoryInitialization(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) line: 895 
XmlWebApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).refresh() line: 425    
DispatcherServlet(FrameworkServlet).createWebApplicationContext(ApplicationContext) line: 442   
DispatcherServlet(FrameworkServlet).createWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContext) line: 458    
DispatcherServlet(FrameworkServlet).initWebApplicationContext() line: 339   
DispatcherServlet(FrameworkServlet).initServletBean() line: 306 
DispatcherServlet(HttpServletBean).init() line: 127 
DispatcherServlet(GenericServlet).init(ServletConfig) line: 241 
ServletHolder.initServlet() line: 421   
ServletHolder.doStart() line: 245   
ServletHolder(AbstractLifeCycle).start() line: 55   
ServletHandler(ServletHandler).initialize() line: 691   
JettyWebAppContext(ServletContextHandler).startContext() line: 204  
JettyWebAppContext(WebAppContext).startContext() line: 995  
JettyWebAppContext(ContextHandler).doStart() line: 588  
JettyWebAppContext(WebAppContext).doStart() line: 381   
JettyWebAppContext.doStart() line: 114  
JettyWebAppContext(AbstractLifeCycle).start() line: 55  
ContextHandlerCollection(HandlerCollection).doStart() line: 165 
ContextHandlerCollection.doStart() line: 162    
ContextHandlerCollection(AbstractLifeCycle).start() line: 55    
HandlerCollection.doStart() line: 165   
HandlerCollection(AbstractLifeCycle).start() line: 55   
JettyServer(HandlerWrapper).doStart() line: 92  
JettyServer(Server).doStart() line: 228 
JettyServer.doStart() line: 67
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actally, you have two Spring application contexts:

- Context loaded by `ContextLoaderListener` from the XML files specified by `context-param` named `contextConfigLocation` (or `applicationContext.xml` by default).
- Context loaded by `DispatcherServlet` from the XML files specified by the dispatcher servlet's `init-param` named `contextConfigLocation` (or `<servletname>-servlet.xml` by default).

The former is a parent context of the latter.

So, you somehow got a definitions of the same bean in both contexts (perhaps, both `contextConfigLocation`s point to the same XML files).

Comment: An interesting idea ... but no. The bean that gets called twice is in exactly one .xml file.  But I do have both the servlet and the dispatcher, and that's wrong, is it not?

Comment: @bmargulies: Show the `web.xml`, please.

Comment: Prob now described in edit. contextConfigLocation included both the context file for security also also a file names springapp-servlet.xml. The dispatcher picked that up automatically, so I ended up with it being loaded *twice*.